# VBA Pivot filter based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create sub that would filter pivot table based on specific cell value. Pivot Table is placed on sheet "Costs" and table's name is also "Costs". The target cell that the filter should be based on is on sheet "Dashboard", cell "D9".

Once the value of cell D9 would change, the filter on sheet Costs would change as well.

There is something wrong in the below code, since it does do nothing and I don't know, where could be the issue. Could you help me, please? The below's code is placed on Sheet3(Dashboard).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Worksheets("Costs").PivotTables("Costs")

If Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 4 Then
    pt.PivotFilters("ProjectID").CurrentPage = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D9").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Many thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is

```
 pt.PivotFields("ProjectID").CurrentPage = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D9").Value
```

Also it's a good idea to clear any previous filters

```
 pt.PivotFields("ProjectID").ClearAllFilters
```